# Tolerant average (ignore #NA, etc.)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to calculate the average over a range (B1:B12 or C1:C12 in the figure), excluding:

1. Cells not being numeric, including Empty strings, Blank cells with no contents, `#NA`, text, etc. (B1+B8:B12 or C1+C8:C12 here).
2. Cells for which corresponding cells in a range (A1:A12 here) have values outside an interval ([7,35] here). This would further exclude B2:B3 or C2:C3.
   At this point, cells in column A may contain numbers or have no contents.

I think it is not possible to use any built-in `AVERAGE`-like function. Then, I tried calculating the sum, the count, and divide. I can calculate the count (F2 and F7), but not the sum (F3), when I have `#N/A` in the range, e.g.

How can I do this?

Notes:

1. Column G shows the formulas in column F.
2. I cannot filter and use `SUBTOTAL`.
3. B8:C8 contain Blank cells with no contents, B9:C9 contain Empty strings.
4. I am looking for (non-user defined) formulas, i.e., non-VBA.

[image]

Comment: How are you getting your #N/A's? Because if they are being produced by a formula you can use `=IFERROR(your formula here, "")`. This is turn all the NA's into blanks which will let you sum and average properly.

Comment: @Loocid - They come from a formula, but I explicitly put them there. I am plotting those ranges, and using `#N/A` avoids having data points at zero for blank cells. See updated figure.

Comment: Ah I see. I'm not then sorry, good luck with fixing your problem :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using *array formulas* based upon nested IFs to provide at least part of the criteria. When an `IF` resolves to **FALSE** it no longer process the **TRUE** portion of the statement.

[image: AVERAGE over ERRORs]

The *array formulas* in F2:F3 are,

```
=SUM(IF(NOT(ISNA(B2:B13)), (A2:A13>=7)*(A2:A13<=35)*(B2:B13<>"")))
=SUM(IF(NOT(ISNA(B2:B13)), IF(B2:B13<>"", (A2:A13>=7)*(A2:A13<=35)*B2:B13)))
```

The *array formulas* in F7:F8 are,

```
=SUM(IF(NOT(ISNA(C2:C13)), (A2:A13>=7)*(A2:A13<=35)*(C2:C13<>"")))
=SUM(IF(NOT(ISNA(C2:C13)), IF(C2:C13<>"", (A2:A13>=7)*(A2:A13<=35)*C2:C13)))
```

Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Once entered correctly, they can be filled down like any other formula if necessary.

Array formulas increase calculation load logarithmically as the range(s) they refer to expand. Try to keep excess blank rows to a minimum and avoid full column references.

Comment: Of course if you just check with ISNUMBER then you can eliminate the blank check, e,g, for average it can be as follows: =AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(C2:C13),IF((A2:A13>=7)*(A2:A13<=35),C2:C13)))

Comment: They work nice! Interesting additional fact about calculation load of array formulas.

Comment: @barryhoudini - Your formula is more versatile than that of the accepted answer (which is ok for the question, anyway). It can be adapted to `STDEV.S`, e.g.

Answer (score 5):

From 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30242599/2103990:

> Providing you are using Excel 2010 and above the [AGGREGATE
>   function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF)
>   can be optioned to ignore all errors.
>
> ```
> =AGGREGATE(1, 6, A1:A5)
> ```
>
> [image: AGGREGATE excluding errors]

Answer (score 1):

You can get the average of your "NA" column values in one fairly simple formula like this:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(
            (
             ($A$2:$A$13>=$F$2)*
             ($A$2:$A$13<=$F$3)*
             ISNUMBER(B2:B13)
                             )>0,
                                 B2:B13))
```

entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter↵</kbd>.

I find this to be a very clear way of writing it, because all your conditions are lined up next to each other. They're "and'ed" using the mathematical operator `*`; this of course converts TRUE and FALSE values to 1's and 0's, respectively, so when the and'ing is done, I convert them back to TRUE/FALSE using `>0`. Note that instead of hard-coding your thresholds 7 and 35 (hard-coding literals is usually considered bad practice), I put them in cells.

[image]

Same logic for your sum and your count; just replace `AVERAGE` with `SUM` and `COUNT`, respectively:

```
=SUM(IF((($A$2:$A$13>=$F$2)*($A$2:$A$13<=$F$3)*ISNUMBER(B2:B13))>0,B2:B13))
=COUNT(IF((($A$2:$A$13>=$F$2)*($A$2:$A$13<=$F$3)*ISNUMBER(B2:B13))>0,B2:B13))
```

though a more succinct formula can also be used for the count:

```
=SUM(($A$2:$A$13>=$F$2)*($A$2:$A$13<=$F$3)*ISNUMBER(B2:B13))
```

The same formulas can be used to average/sum/count your "blank" column. Here I just drag-copied them one column to the right (column G), which means that all instances of `B2:B13` became `C2:C13`.

Comment: Your formula is more versatile than that of the accepted answer (which is ok for the question, anyway). It can be adapted to `STDEV.S`, e.g.