# AVERAGEIF(range, criteria) formula that ignores errors in the data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do you specify the criteria if you want to average a range of numbers but want to ignore errors using the AVERAGEIF() function?

For example, given the data below:

```
A1: 1
A2: #DIV/0!
A3: #VALUE!
A4: 5
A5: 0
```

Wanting to use the AVERAGEIF(range, criteria) formula something like this:

```
=AVERAGEIF(a1:a5,and("<>#DIV/0!","<>#VALUE!"))
                    or
=AVERAGEIF(a1:a5,"<>Error()")
```

Is there a way to specify a criteria to exclude errors?  The answer I expect from the range is 2, the average of the three valid numbers (1, 5, & 0).

I found, via searches, that there is a way to do this using an array formula or other functions, but I want to find out if there is a way to do this without an array formula or using another function.  Basically, can you specify in the criteria to ignore errors.  One error can be ignored like this:

```
AVERAGEIF(a1:a5,"<>#DIV/0!")
```

But how to specify to ignore any errors?  This is a criteria question, using Microsoft Excel 2013.

Comment: Please try `AVERAGEIFS` - you can add 2 conditions there. The second approach could be a combination of `AVERAGE`, `IF` and `ISERROR` functions in an array formula.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will work as long as there aren't any negative numbers in your data:

```
=AVERAGEIF(A1:A5,">=0")
```

Comment: You can include negatives, if required, by using this version `=AVERAGEIF(A1:A5,"<=9.99E+307")`

Answer (score 14):

Providing you are using Excel 2010 and above the [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) can be optioned to ignore all errors.

```
=AGGREGATE(1, 6, A1:A5)
```

[image: AGGREGATE excluding errors]

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option would be to use AVERAGEIFS, excluding the specific errors.

```
=AVERAGEIFS(A13:A17,A13:A17,"<>#DIV/0!",A13:A17,"<>#VALUE!")
```

HOWEVER, I would strongly recommend that instead of this work around, you address the actual issue of having errors in your data.

For example, where you have the #DIV/0! error, put in an IF to check for a zero, and if it finds one, replace the error with an empty string:

```
=IF(X=0,"",Y)
```

AVERAGE will then automatically ignore these strings.

Without knowing more about what is causing your errors, I cannot make more specific suggestions to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a wildcard character to ignore all errors, assuming every error starts with '#' and ends with '!'.

=AVERAGEIFS(A13:A17,A13:A17,"<>#*!")