# Average Values from Specific Dates

Tags: excel, date, average

I have a column of dates in the form 2011-05-18 (yyyy-mm-dd), and have a column of strictly digits.

I have tried using the averageif function:

=AVERAGEIF(A:A,YEAR=2012,N:N)

but this always returns #DIV/0! , even if that year does exist in the dataset.

I want to be able to compile a list of averages **for each year** (i.e. yearly average), and plot this data in a year vs. average values graphs. I do not want to have to manually determine averages for each year :( Any ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Tolerant average (ignore #NA, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29292272/tolerant-average-ignore-na-etc) (which is even more demanding than the present case),

```
=AVERAGE(IF(YEAR(A:A)=2012,N:N))
```

with Ctrl+Shift+Enter works (tested).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a cleaner way, but this works for me:

```
=SUM((YEAR(A:A)=2013)*N:N)/SUM((YEAR(A:A)=2013)*1)
```

entered as an array formula using Ctrl+Shift+Enter