# excel nested if multiple logical tests

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested

I have read other threads on this topic, however I found no answers.
I have three colums, of which I want to test column a and b and if true I want the som of the results in colum c.

```
         a      b      c
  1     ba     za       2
  2     ba     az       2
  3     ca     za       2
  4     ca     az       2 
  5     ba     za       2
```

I want to find the sum if column a = ba and column b = za. So in this example the sum of those would be 4. This is the Excel forumala I have, however it keeps giving the result of 0.

This formula is a nested if.

`=Sum(IF(And((a1:a5="ba");b1:b5="za");c1:c5;0))`

Can someone please help me with finding the correct formula? I have been breaking my head about this particular formula.

I have been using excel for a while now, and quite got the hang of all the formulas, however this is the only problem I could not wrap my head around.

Comment: What Excel version? Maybe simply `SUMIFS` is the solution? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b

Comment: Did you find any answer useful? (you did not provide feedback/marked answers).

Answer (score 1):

You should be using commas instead of semi-colons. I'd suggest adding another column (Lets say column C) and input the formula:

```
=IF(AND(A1="ba", B1="za"), 1, 0)
```

You can hide this column from view if you want. Then use this to get your answer

```
=SUMIF(C1:C5,1,D1:D5)
```

so my dataset looks like:

```
+---+----+----+---+----+
|   | A  | B  | C | D  |
+---+----+----+---+----+
| 1 | ba | za | 1 |  2 |
| 2 | ba | az | 0 |  2 |
| 3 | ca | za | 0 |  2 |
| 4 | ca | az | 0 |  2 |
| 5 | ba | za | 1 |  2 |
+---+----+----+---+----+
```

Which gives me an answer of 4

Or you could use `SUMIFS`

```
=SUMIFS(D1:D5,A1:A5,"ba",B1:B5,"za")
```

Which will also give you an answer of 4

Answer (score 1):

As per [Tolerant average (ignore #NA, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29292272/2707864) and its answers, this should work.

```
=SUM(IF(($a$1:$a$5="ba")*($b$1:$b$5="za"),$c$1:$c$5))
```

entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter↵</kbd>.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($a$1:$a$5="ba")*($b$1:$b$5="za")*($c$1:$c$5))
```

should work as well.

Note that you may have to change usage of absolute/relative referencing.