# VBA code to ignore all #N/A values in a column to calculate Average

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for a code to ignore all the #N/A values in the column of data, and find the average of all the remaining cells, and return this average value to a cell. Currently I have this code; it works if the selected data range contains no #N/A, however if there are some #N/A data points, the entire average just returns as #N/A.

I have also tried this code and to no avail (DateRange is the range of dates that is user specified in my sheet, I want to show the value returned in cell O5):

```
Range("O5").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(DateRange).Formula = "=AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(DateRange)),DateRange"
```

The working code for no values of #N/A:

```
Dim DataPts As Range
Set DataPts = Range(FromDateCell, ToDateCell).Offset(0, 1)
Range("O5").Value = Application.Average(DataPts)
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29292272/tolerant-average-ignore-na-etc

Comment: in Excel 2010 and above [`=AGGREGATE(1,6,range)`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df) can be used to ignore errors

Comment: Thank you! Aggregate worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

I am going to risk being downvoted and give you a simpler but handy **trick** to try:

```
=AVERAGEIF(myRange,"<1e100")
```

(provided you dont have such big numbers in you range).

Comment: Sometimes a risk pays off. A quick kludge is sometimes better than a bullet-proof answer.

Answer (score 1):

or you could use [SpecialCells()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157(v=office.15).aspx) method:

```
Range("O5").Formula = "=AVERAGE(" & range(DateRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas,xlNumbers).address & ")"
```

or, if you just need the *value* instead of the *formula* returning the *value*:

```
Range("O5").Value=WorksheetFunction.Average(range(DateRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas,xlNumbers))
```